# How To Use Conditional Statements in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

sortinoIndex is a vector that contain NA and numeric numbers I want create a loop to extract only the numeric numbers and save them into sortino1
how can I do? I did this but does not work can you help me?

```
    sortino1<-numeric()
for (i in 1:252) {
  if(sortinoIndex[i]!=NA){
    sortino1[i]<-sortinoIndex[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't do what you want it to do. Have you tried running it?

Comment: Nothing ever "equals" (or for that matter "not equals") an NA. Learn to use `is.na`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, we typically won't use a `for` loop to do something like this, because it is very slow compared to implementing the same loop in C++.

Instead, we'll use a vectorized operation:

Create some data:

```
set.seed(10)
sortinoIndex <- sample(c(NA,1:10),25, replace = TRUE)
```

Remove `NA` values:

```
sortino1 <- sortinoIndex[!is.na(sortinoIndex)]
print(sortino1)

[1] 5 3 4 7 2 3 2 6 4 7 6 1 6 3 4 2 4 9 9 6 8 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `complete.cases`

```
sortinoIndex[complete.cases(sortinoIndex)]
```